# .NET CF Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a problem that can basically be summirized as:

```
Byte[] barr = new Byte[25 * 1024 * 1024];
// use barr
```

The problem is that this cause an Out Of Memory exception.

A simple solution could be to allocate this memory "by chunks" and process a chunk at a time, but I cannot do that because I am using an external library that wants all the data to be processed in a whole.

More details about the application:

- The data to process is a Bitmap obtained by a laser imager (EMDK framework)
- I process the Bitmap saving in "barr" each 3rd byte of the Bitmap
- I pass "barr" to an external library that perform a gradient analysis and returns valid/invalid
- Loop until valid and save the bitmap

To not use that external library is not a feasable solution! (unfortunately)

Comment: you get the bytes from the externel component - right? If yes why copy this to another array?

Comment: will the external library **only** accept a single `byte[]`? no `Stream`? no fragment-based API where you call it lots of times? If so, I'm not sure what you want us to say...

Comment: @ Carsten Konig: Just because I need to "extract" every 3rd byte.

Comment: you want to allocate 25MB in a small memory device...

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: I can only pass a single byte[] to that library.

Comment: @ vulcanino: yes I know, but the device has over 150M available... and my application is the only one that will run on that device. I would like to use all the space available!

Comment: what method/class do you call in emdk framework, could you provide us with a link pls

Comment: @Cristiano - There is no reason you cannot fill a byte[] with 150MB worth of data.  That is an extremly small amount of data.  Can you post the code in question, the single line you provided, would not cause a Out of Memory exception by itself.

Comment: @Ramhound There are no guarantees whatsoever about the amount of available contiguous memory.

Comment: found a link to an explanation causing your code to crash. CF is limited to 32MB of virtual RAM! (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/0926afcf-9720-41ca-a067-1377a2269bbf/) Assuming there are some other programs runing on your mobile device, eg. OS, ..  you may never get 25MB of free RAM

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz Thanks for the link, I wonder if there is any way to increase virtual RAM, but I don't think so...

Comment: Does your API provide any way to direct the data to file? If so, you could then handle the file stream on your own terms.

Comment: Basically, the library gives a static class with a public byte[]. I need to fill the byte[] and call the process method. The problem is to fill the byte[] with the correct data without going out of memory.

Comment: Is it feasible in your scenario to offload the gradient analysis to some service on the network?  That way you could still leverage the 3rd party component, but you could do it on a machine with some more memory.

Comment: @RQDQ No, it is not feasable.

Comment: Might also explore the possibility of a memory mapped file to overcome the attempt to declare a 25MB array in this case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to validate the bitmap by pixel row?  If the current row is not valid, push in the next row until you receive a valid reply?